# Check if java.lang.reflect.Field type is a byte array

Tags: java, reflection

I don't do much of reflection so this question might be obvious. For e.g. I have a class:

```
public class Document {

    private String someStr;    

    private byte[] contents;  

    //Getters and setters

}
```

I am trying to check if the field `contents` is an instance of byte array. What I tried:

```
Class clazz = Document.class;
Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getType().isArray()) {
        Object array = field.getType();
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

The output of this code is: `class [B`. I see that byte array is found, but if I do:

```
if (array instanceof byte[]) {...}
```

This condition is never `true`. Why is that? And how to check if the object contains fields which are of type of `byte[]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`array instanceof byte[]` checks whether `array` is an object of type `byte[]`. But in your case `array` is not a `byte[]`, it's an object of type `Class` that represents `byte[]`.

You can access a `Class` that represents some type `T` as `T.class`, therefore you need the following check:

```
if (array == byte[].class) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

if the array is a class only `instanceof Class` will be true..

If you want to check the type of a field you can use

```
if(field.getType() == byte[].class)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Class<?> cls = field.getType();
if (cls.isAssignableFrom(byte[].class)) {
    System.out.println("It's a byte array");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this useful tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html)

> Array types may be identified by invoking Class.isArray()

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
Class<?> array = field.getType();
System.out.println(array.getCanonicalName());
```

it prints `byte[]`. But @axtavt's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need is

```
field.getType().getTypeName().equals("byte[]")
```